# Was there ever cadmium in LEGO bricks?

Tags: history, safety

I remember a rumour from my youth in the late seventies / early eighties, that there was supposedly cadmium in older (relative to that time) LEGO bricks.

Searching for `LEGO cadmium` yields quite a lot of hits, but so far, nothing conclusive.
I also note that LEGO has never recalled any old bricks, which I admit would be next to impossible: how would the general public be able to distinguish between older and newer bricks?

**Has cadmium ever been used in LEGO bricks? If so, in what quantities?**

How about other toxic metals?

Comment: What an interesting question! I'm going to ask my older LEGO friends to see if anyone knows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked Gary Istok on your behalf in [this Brickset Forum thread](http://bricksetforum.com/discussion/comment/498950), who is an expert on LEGO's history. He said the following:

> When LEGO replaced the Cellulose Acetate bricks circa 1963 with ABS
>   plastic for non-trans parts, and polycarbonate for the trans ones,
>   they had a problem with the red and yellow parts.  For some reason
>   (I'm not a chemical engineer)... red and yellow ABS parts were more
>   difficult to color to TLG standards.  So Bayer and Borg-Warner (the
>   chemical companies that produced the ABS and other plastic pellets
>   worldwide) added Cadmium, a heavy metal, as an additive to those 2
>   LEGO colors to help in the coloring process.
>
> Although Cadmium will not leach out of the LEGO bricks of that era (kids could safely chew on those LEGO parts), the longer term landfill
>   issues of Cadmium laced LEGO getting into the ground, did become an
>   issue with environmentalists.  So TLG had their plastics makers
>   Borg-Warner (for USA, Canada, Britain, Ireland and Australia) and
>   Bayer (for continental Europe and Asia) work on removing the cadmium
>   from the red and yellow elements of that era.  I don't know the
>   chemical specifics of that action, but by 1973 LEGO parts were Cadmium
>   free... and have remained so.
>
> Next question.... can you tell Cadmium parts (1963-72) from Cadmium free parts?  Generally yes... but it's easier for red bricks, which
>   are a darker red color with Cadmium.  Yellow LEGO parts with Cadmium
>   are also a darker color, but the difference between Cadmium and
>   Cadmium free yellow parts is less noticeable... especially with used
>   or dirty yellow elements.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadmium_pigments

Comment: Fixed thread link: https://forum.brickset.com/discussion/comment/498950

Answer (score 2):

Even in early 1980s there were some patches having Cadmium. I should link to the study but lost it now.

Here is somewhat proper reference:

https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/5436922/second-hand-plastic-toys-including-lego-could-harm-children-with-toxic-chemicals/

Eating is something to avoid. Hand-to-mouth (hand skin licked) behaviour is not as fatal.