# What set are these large quarter circle curved bricks from?

Tags: set-identification

I got a random box of Lego!  I'm trying to figure out what set these bricks are from:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 11):

Few pieces to be certain, but I believe it's from the set Maula's Ice Mammoth Stomper (70145):

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70145-1

Comment: You might want to mention that that part (https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=87559&in=S) only appears in one set with this piece (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138&idColor=15#T=C&C=15) on it.

Comment: I find it very interesting that LEGO [was so reluctant to add basic green pieces out of fear kids would build tanks with them](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/why-was-lego-reluctant-to-use-additional-colours-for-regular-bricks-in-former-ti/12944#12944), yet here they are adding a whole mobile weapons platform.

Comment: @MechMK1 Times do change, indeed. LEGO now* embraces the philosophy of teaching the concepts of good, evil and struggle by releasing conflict-based sets with clearly identifiable good and bad sides. Or, if you prefer cynicism, they see that there is market demand for such sets and are willing to compromise somewhat. *_Note: there were such sets even in the '80s, see for example the [1989 Space Police theme](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Space/subtheme-Space-Police)._

Comment: @zovitssupportsGoFundMonica I personally am not opposed to the idea of teaching such concepts, given how popular [games](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/) [for](https://clashroyale.com/) [kids](https://supercell.com/en/games/clashofclans/) are all based around cartoonified violence (with a distinct lack of identifiable good and evil) anyways. But the reason why I brought it up was that the lack of a basic color for such a specific reason seemed like it was very important for the company, and it seems weird to just throw that out of the window for profits.